# Prove that $\lim_{x\to0^+}[1+[x]]^{\frac{2}{x}}=1$,where $[x]$ represents the floor function of $x$

Tags: limits

Prove that $\lim_{x\to0^+}[1+[x]]^{\frac{2}{x}}=1$,where $[x]$ represents the floor function of $x$

---

$\lim_{x\to0^+}[1+[x]]^{\frac{2}{x}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}[1]^{\frac{2}{x}}$
Because $\lim_{x\to0^+}[x]=0$
But i am stuck.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: The numbers become $1^{200},1^{2000},1^{200000}$, which are $1,1,1$, so the limit is 1.

Comment: You nailed it man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $x$ gets small enough (in fact, only $<1$ does the job), $[x]$ is exactly $0$ (this is very different from saying that it has a zero limit).

This allows us to say that for small enough $x$, $(1 + [x])^{2/x} = 1^{2/x} = 1$ and so has a limit $1$.

Comment: But in $1^{\frac{2}{x}},\frac{2}{x}$ tends to infinity.Isn't it?So this is in the form of $1^{\infty}$@Ahmed Hussein

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia, the form $1^\infty$ refers to $f(x)^{g(x)}$ where $f(x)\to 1$ and $g(x)\to\infty$.  When $f(x)$ is identically $1$, as in this example, it isn't an indeterminate form anymore.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(1+\lfloor{x}\rfloor\right)^{\frac{2}{x}}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\exp\left(\ln\left(\left(1+\lfloor{x}\rfloor\right)^{\frac{2}{x}}\right)\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\exp\left(\frac{2\ln\left(1+\lfloor{x}\rfloor\right)}{x}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2\ln\left(1+\lfloor{x}\rfloor\right)}{x}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(2\left(\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln\left(1+\lfloor{x}\rfloor\right)}{x}\right)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(2\left(0\right)\right)=\exp\left(0\right)=e^0=1$$